# How can I handle the below coverity scan issue Parameter docId receives the tainted data (taint_path_param)

Tags: java, coverity, coverity-prevent

Please find my code snippet.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/abc" , Method=RequetMethod.GET)
    public void xxx(@Requestparam("docId") final String docId , @Requestparam("archieveId") final String archieveId){
//Code will be here
}
```

How can I resolve the coverity scan issues which says "**TAINTED_PATH_PARAM**"
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

As per description provided in [link](https://community.synopsys.com/s/article/Tainted-data-in-Coverity)

> The program does not have control over the values of the input, and so
>   before using this data, the program must sanitise the data to
>   eliminate system crashes, corruption, escalation of privileges, or
>   denial of service.

`@Requestparam("docId") final String docId` can be taken as *tained_source*, which might be sinking at one or multiple places.

**Solution :** Validation of this variable before *"sink"* with **@NotNull** or **@NotEmpty** or **spacial characters validation** might resolve this issue.

Comment: The tool suggests @ notTainted annotation, trying to download jar for that and see.. will try with @ notNull and @ notTainted will update you